# Make files in a directory not visible to anyone

Tags: permissions, directory

I need to make files in a directory invisible to everyone. Through invisible I mean that the file must not show up when I use the `find *` command.

My efforts: I was thinking of using the `chmod` command but was not able to find a particular permission that may serve my task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove the read permission on the directory for the other users e.g. by

```
chmod 700 dirname
```

You cannot allow access to a directory and hide just some of the files it contains.